# Code for syncing the iPhone with REST-servers

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rest, synchronization

is there any open source code for syncing an iPhone
with a server (preferably REST)?

Found nothing on github and google code.

Regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using the excellent ASIHTTPRequest source from All-Seeing Interactive: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest. I'm doing this, and so are several released iPhone apps, so you can be sure the code is pretty solid.

This is a wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications.

It is suitable for performing basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE). The ASIFormDataRequest subclass makes it easy to submit POST data and files using multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with a project called [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/getting-started) (Github project here: http://github.com/yfactorial/objectiveresource/tree/master), which is focused mainly on the communication layer between your iphone models and a REST based web service.  It is targeted at rails applications but should work with any REST api.  Part of that project is a more sync oriented solution that is still in early development, but which has been discussed quite a bit lately in the objective resource google group at http://groups.google.com/group/objectiveresource?hl=en.

I highly recommend objective resource, I've been using it along with sqlitepersistenobjects to handle sync on my iphone project.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Adrian Kosmaczewski's [iPhone Rest Wrapper](http://github.com/akosma/iphonerestwrapper/tree/master) with success.  See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630306/iphone-rest-client).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend checking out RestKit: http://restkit.org/ It provides an excellent API for accessing RESTful web services and representing the remote resources as local objects, including persisting them to Core Data.