# Does any body have a simple application using REST api

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i m the beginner in iphone programming i want to make an application which will receive data from REST api by using php web server. and can post something to it.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone REST client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630306/iphone-rest-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is a library written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications.

It is suitable performing basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE).

The library includes a sample iPhone application.

Answer (score 0):

Check these out:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtgr8-a3/ (REST is working, SOAP library exists but not integrated to front end)

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtgr8-jigsaw/ has rest implementation.