# Consuming SOAP web services on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, web-services

I am trying to write applications for iPad which take advantage of web services.  I know the concept of a web service and have used it in C#/.NET.  I need to know how to do this on an iPad.  Can anyone recommend a good book or reading material on webservices for iOS?

Comment: What type of web services are you trying to consume?  REST based services or SOAP?

Comment: Sorry,  SOAP.  I am not familiar with REST.

Comment: I would recommend you look at RESTful services instead.  The reason being is that they are much more lightweight and with the limited hardware and bandwidth of an iPhone/iPad, you'll probably get better results.

Comment: This one : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/invoke-soap-web-service.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using iOS frameworks, your solution will involve using [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) or [NSRLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In-depth Apple documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html). In my experience, you want to wrap those API calls in your own client request that can build data transfer objects your application logic understands.

If you're looking at 3rd party frameworks to access a RESTful web service, take a peek at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630306/iphone-rest-client) for a number of iOS framework options.

For SOAP services, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone).

As for processing the data, it depends what kind of data your web service produces. There are several frameworks and libraries that can make it easy to consume XML or [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application).

In my experience, the best book on the subject is [Advanced iOS Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470971231).