# WebSeal Authentication

Tags: ios, webseal

I am currently trying to Authenticate through WebSeal to a web service from within my iOS application. I just cannot seem to find anything that sets me in the right direction.  Thus far i am using a NSURLRequest but i cannot seem to pass through the SOAP action and get a response from WebSeal, could anyone put me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope these links point you in the right direction.

1. [How to Access SOAP Services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)
2. [Consuming SOAP Web Services on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388930/consuming-soap-web-services-on-ios)
3. [Handling SOAP with iPhone](http://abhicodehelp.blogspot.com/2010/12/handling-soap-with-iphone.html)
4. [iPhone Programming Tutorial – Intro to SOAP Web Services](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)