# How to consume web service java JAX-WS with client in iOS?

Tags: java, ios

I need consume a Web Service created with Java JAX-WS, I need to create a client web service in app iOS. but i don't know how.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388930/consuming-soap-web-services-on-ios ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have found a solution from my problem. First i make a web service Rest and using two libraries  [JSON framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads) and [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for the web service cliente.

So that's all, I hope to help somebody.